# Classification of multiple values at the same point

Tags: qgis, classification

If I have a point dataset with multiple values for the same geographic location (e.g. residuals from a regression where multiple individuals live at the same location) which I classify using quantile classification in QGIS, how does QGIS choose which quantile (in practice which color) to show on the map? For example, if there are three values for a single location with values falling within e.g. the first, second and fifth quantile, how does QGIS choose what to represent on the map?

Comment: I always thought it was the symbol ordering which is used to show what appears on the map going from bottom-up. E.g. if your order from top is 1st, 2nd, 5th, then the 5th symbology would be shown first, then 2nd etc.

Comment: Ah! That does sound like a plausible explanation.

Comment: You can also set the priority of which symbols should appear above others by setting the **symbol levels**. In your style interface, go to `Advanced > Symbol levels` and give each symbol a number (high numbers will be shown before low numbers).